# Hide GUID in core search results display

Tags: xslt, search-results

I have created a number of Managed Properties, so I could customize Refinement Panel - this ia all good.  Search Core Results WebPart now displays some of these new managed properties with value, GUID, etc (each part of the property separated with ;#).  How can I update to just display the value?  I understand it will require some XSLT, but not sure what I need to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this guide to Step 4. - [Guide](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/17/display-custom-fields-in-sharepoint-2010-search-results-webpart/)

From here, go back your browser with the open page. Hit F12 (Web developer (IE), FireBug (FireFox), WebKit (Chrome, Safari)) and inspect the element. Find the DIV (or other container surrounding this value) and then go back to your XSLT, find it and either comment it out or remove it.

Or you could go to the Fetched Properties (Right above XSL-editor) in the Edit Panel and remove the column(s). Then they won't be displayed in the search results as they aren't present in the query.

Hope this helps :)